# Parallel downloads using pySmartDL - python multiprocess

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I'm hoping to use [pySmartDL](http://itaybb.github.io/pySmartDL/) for my project to handle downloads. But pySmartDL doesn't support parallel downloads and the execution thread stops until a download is finished. I tried using [WorQ](http://worq.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to handle the issue. But with that download doesn't happen after I start it.Is there a better way to address this issue? Or is there any other Python libraries that support parallel downloads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pySmartDL` already supports nonblocking multithreaded downloads:

```
from pySmartDL import SmartDL

files = [URL1,
         URL2,
         URL3]

objs = SmartDL(files, progress_bar=False)
objs.start(blocking=False)
while not objs.isFinished():
    # Do something else
```